# Chrome Extension e2e testing with nightwatchjs - How to open an URL from within project?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, e2e-testing, nightwatch.js

Im working on an e2e test case using nightwatchjs on my chrome extension project. I have two test cases, the first one finished okay, but the second one which targets a URL opens as an HTTP 404 (not found).

My goal is to open the HTML page within the project so I can run cases using imported functions from other files. Anyone can advise me on how to achieve this?

My code:

```
describe('Test Extension', function() {
    before(browser => {
        browser.url('chrome-extension://cnneliealkphmbbcmlhnbfhje/index.html#/menu/configuration')
    });

    it('Test Context menu buttons', function (browser) {
        browser.expect.title().to.equal('Test Extension');
        browser.expect.element('#title').text.to.equal('Test Extension')
        browser.click('#loginButton')
        browser.click('#userName')
        browser.setValue('#userName input', 'testUser')
        browser.click('#userPassword')
        browser.setValue('#userPassword input', 'testPassword')
        browser.click('#signIn')
        browser.pause(5)
        browser.click('#enableSwitch')
        browser.click('#enableSwitch2')
        browser.click('#saveSubmit')
    });

    it('Api test call', function (browser) {
        browser
            .url('http://localhost:9514/test/e2e/specs/test.html')
            .pause()
        browser.expect.element('#caseId').text.to.equal('1000')
        .moveToElement('#caseId')
        .mouseButtonDown(2)
        .mouseButtonUp(2)
        .end();
    });

    after(browser => browser.end());
});
```

The first 'it' case works fine, but the second 'it' case when trying to access the internal html page 'http://localhost:9514/test/e2e/specs/test.html' it fails as 404.

I have tried adding the full path and it still does not work.
Anyone can tell me what I'm missing?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to open the URL in a new tab and continue from there.

To open the URL in a new tab you have you have to use:

```
.execute(function() {
  return window.open('http://localhost:9514/test/e2e/specs/test.html', '_blank')
})
```

To move to the tab where your URL is opened you have to use:

```
.windowHandles(function(result) {
  var handle = result.value[1];
  browser.switchWindow(handle);
})
```

Now combining both your second test case should look like:

```
it('Api test call', function(browser) {
  browser
    .execute(function() {
      return window.open('http://localhost:9514/test/e2e/specs/test.html', '_blank')
    })
    .windowHandles(function(result) {
      var handle = result.value[1];
      browser.switchWindow(handle);
    })
  browser.expect.element('#caseId').text.to.equal('1000')
    .moveToElement('#caseId')
    .mouseButtonDown(2)
    .mouseButtonUp(2)
    .end();
});
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for your feedback. This code tries to open the URL in a new tab, however, the URL does not open as it returns HTTP 404 (not found). I have tried to add the full path of the .html file but still does not open. Im wondering it is not possible to open a html page that is within the project with nightwatchjs.

Comment: If you open the url in a normal browser, is it opening ?

Comment: Yes if i open the URL in normal browser with full path it works fine (/Users/user1/Desktop/git/test/e2e/specs/test.html). But when i tried to open the same internal URL within the nightwatchjs testing i get a 404 not found

Comment: Keep the html file in the Nightwatch JS in the project root and then try `window.open('test.html', '_blank')`

Comment: Still not found. From the URL box, i see its trying to access this URL "chrome-extension://cnneliealkphmbbcmlhnbfhjegfpagfc/test.html" Im wondering if there is a limitation with nightwatch e2e when using chrome extension

Comment: I am not sure if this will work but if you check the test for the html page first than the chrome extension ?